# How to tell if a control is no longer visible to the user?

Tags: windows-runtime

I have a control in which I repeatedly run some animations (e.g. DoubleAnimation). Can I detect if my control is no longer visible to the user? E.g it gets scrolled away from, the user navigates forward to another page, or it gets obscured behind other controls.
I don't want to run those animations unless at least some part of my control is visible for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could analyze the visual tree or get a transform from control coordinates to screen coordinates to see if its positioning is within the view port and also check things like opacities, visibilities etc. of controls down the visual tree path, but that is so processing intensive that it is not worth doing all the time for a general solution.

The only thing that would make sense is to handle the `ScrollViewer.ViewChanged` event and check if the offsets make it visible or not while limiting the `TransformToVisual` or `VisualTreeHelper` calls only to times when the actual layout within your `ScrollViewer` changes.

Comment: I was hoping for something built-in or easy to implement, something lightweight. I will contend with stopping the animation when the user navigates to another page. Thanks for the reply!